# Como ver multimedia en un navegador web hecho en java

Tags: java, javafx

He creado un navegador web muy basico usando javafx, aparentemente funciona, el detalle es que al ingresar a cualquier pagina que tenga algun video, no lo puedo visualizar, me gustaria seber como puedo mejorar este detalle.

Answer (score 0):

Yo también tuve problemas implementando un navegador en JavaFX, en mi caso fue para visualizar el street view de google maps, te recomiendo que implementes el Framework **JCEF** basado en Chromium, le da un plus a tu proyecto:

[The Java Chromium Embedded Framework (JCEF) is a simple framework for embedding Chromium-based browsers in other applications using the Java programming language.](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef)

Y si no tienes problemas con gastar un "poco" tambien te recomiendo **JxBrowser**:
[Integrate a Chromium-based browser with your Java app to process and display HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript, Flash etc.](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser)

En lo personal use ambos y los dos son muy buenos, pero JxBrowser tiene facilidades que tu tendrias que implementar en JCEF.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, me ha servido de utilidad, lo interesante es que JxBrowser es pago, hay manera de que sea gratis, que me parece bien para estudios.

Comment: En la pagina cuentan con una Versión de evaluación, puedes usar esa, o puedes optar por JCEF, (que básicamente es el motor de JxBrowser).